# How to best handle bit data in C#?

Tags: c#, bit, binary-data

I'm trying to implement different signals containing different data and I  implemented various datatypes in C# to manage the data cleanly (mainly structs, some enums). Most of these types are oddly sized, say some are 9 bit or 3 bit etc.

I implemented them as their closest equivalent basic C# type (most are byte, ushort or short, with some ints and uints).

What is the general way of handling such data types in C#? In the end I have to combine all the bits into one byte array, but I'm not sure how to combine them.

I thought about getting the byte array of each type with a BitConverter and putting all data as booleans into a BitArray which I than can convert back to a byte array. But I can't seem to split the byte array.

Another way to do it would be shifting every single variable I have, but that seems really dirty to do. If a type changed from 32 bit to 31 bit in the future that would seem like a hassle to change.

How is this usually done? Any best practices or something?

Basically I want to combine different sized data into one byte array. For example pack a 3 bit variable, a 2 bit boolean and a 11 bit value into 2 bytes.

Since I have the types implemented as C# types I can do `BitArray arr = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)MyType))`, but this would give me 16 bit while `MyType` might only have 9 bit.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Some context would help.

Comment: I want to combine different sized data into one byte array. For example pack a 3 bit variable, a 2 bit boolean and a 11 bit value into 2 bytes

Comment: Please clarify how exactly you want to put those odd-sized bit-groups into a byte array. How would they be aligned and packed, etc... ? Also, what is this byte-array-splitting business about? Please do not exaplain and clarify your question here in the comments. **Edit** and improve the question itself... ;-)

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: Don't use BitConverter, it makes your life just painful as it is not geared towards odd-sized bit-groups but intended to be used for the "normal-sized" primitive value types. Instead, i would suggest you write helper methods (could be methods of your types, static or extension methods) that take one of your values and create an appropriate BitArray (or writing the value into an existing BitArray) just using the methods provided by the BitArray type. Analogous, you could then also write a method (or methods) that take a BitArray and extract those odd-sized values from whatever BitArray position

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks. So there is no way other than iterating over the varible via shifting and setting every bit in the BitArray manually? Also, what should I do with Enums? Capsule them into another type?

Comment: Start by building a very clear abstraction that expresses *at the level of your business domain* what the operations on data are.  The bit-level operations -- the shifting and twiddling and whatnot -- are implementation details of that abstraction, and you can change those details as you see fit.  **Design the code for the convenience of the person reading and maintaining the call sites**, not for the convenience of the person implementing the API. The first question to answer is "if I were reading the *calls* to my API, how would it read, ideally?"

Comment: "_Also, what should I do with Enums? Capsule them into another type?_" What about them, why encapsulate? I am not sure i understand the reasoning behind these questions...

Comment: Nevermind, I'm confusing myself. I could just make a `Convert(long, NumberOfBits)` function that takes any 64 bit and returns a BitArray. I was stuck on having a Type.ToBitArray() function inside each type, which wouldn't work for enums.

Comment: As I understand this, you're trying to add multiple data elements to a single byte array.   Why do you have to combine them into a byte array at all?  Is this for storage or transmission with the smallest possible memory footprint? Is there some reason you can't use a DTO or dictionary?

Comment: This is for transmission, yes. I never worked on stuff this low level, so I don't know how this is done usually.

Comment: Why are you trying to use oddball bit sizes? Is there a use case for this?

Why not use the first n bits (up to a maximum) and leave the largest bits unused?

Comment: @ScubaSteve The data are controller signals used in autonomous driving, so I want to sent as few as possible. It's just how the specification goes.

Comment: What protocol are you using to transmit the signals?

Comment: @ScubaSteve I don't know, probably UDP? My task is only to implement the data structures and the packing as binary data in C#.

Comment: Okay, I think what you're trying to do is compress your bit stream, to keep it as small as possible? You don't need to do that. The transport layer will compress things.

What's the maximum number of bits you'll need? Store everything using that, and use the least significant bits first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My task is only to implement the data structures and the packing as
>   binary data in C#

**To explicitly manipulate the in-memory layout of your structures:**

Use `StructLayout`.  Generally, this is only appropriate if dealing with interop or specialized memory constraints. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute) for examples/documentation. Note that you'll take a performance hit if your data is not byte-aligned.

**To design a data structure:**

Just use an existing solution like [ASN.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asn.1) or [Protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers).  This problem has already been addressed by experts; take advantage of their skills and knowledge.  As an added bonus, using standard protocols makes it far easier for third parties to implement custom interfaces.

Comment: Is there a ASN.1 library for C# or is the `AsnEncodedData` class which seems to be in System.Security.Cryptography all I need?

Comment: @sollniss: I don't think `AsnEncodedData` supports all encodings, though it might be good enough to suit your needs.  However, I don't recommend it.  Generalized ASN.1 support is [under consideration](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/21833).  There are a few paid and free libraries for ASN.1.  However, I would recommend Protobuf, especially [Protobuf.Net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net).  Protobuf.Net is designed to use idiomatic C#, so you'll probably find it easier to work worth.